# What's the use of Invoke() in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, invoke

I found this code:

```
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(EventGetSum));
```

Is this not the same as writing:

```
EventGetSum();
```

What's the use of this?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571706/shortest-way-to-write-a-thread-safe-access-method-to-a-windows-forms-control/571749#571749

Comment: That's a pretty bad title, maybe you should consider changing it to something more descriptive

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you write `EventGetSum()` that immediately *calls* the EventGetSum method.

If you write `new EventHandler(EventGetSum)` that creates a delegate which will (in turn) call EventGetSum when it's invoked.

The call to [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) invokes the given delegate from the UI thread responsible for the control. This is necessary because you mustn't access UI elements from arbitrary threads.

Answer (score 5):

It executes the `EventGetSum` method in the thread to that the window `this` belongs to.

Answer (score 4):

This is normally used when dealing with cross thread UI calls.

Look at the MSDN documentation for ISynchronizeInvoke.