# Running threads in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have an application in which I am running a separate thread.

```
Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Main)
thread.Start()
```

However, the thread makes reference to an textbox named Output, and it generates this error upon execution:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Output' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
```

(message shortened for space)

How can I make the operations run on another thread, but still use the Output object? I cannot call a subroutine to do that for me, as it generates the exact same error.

The method called is AppendText, by the way.

I am probably missing something important here, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just calling the `AppendText` method you need to force it to execute on the correct thread. So, if you have a call like this:

```
myTextBox.AppendText("some text")
```

...you need to change it to this:

```
myTextBox.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf myTextBox.AppendText), "some text")
```

You can use either `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`. In this case, since `AppendText` doesn't have any return value, `BeginInvoke` is a good choice (the difference is that `Invoke` will block the current thread while the GUI thread executes the `AppendText` method, while `BeginInvoke` will make the call asynchronously instead).

Answer (score 1):

You should use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to call your subroutine.

Comment: @Cyclone: see this other post for examples of using InvokeRequired and Invoke: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571706/shortest-way-to-write-a-thread-safe-access-method-to-a-windows-forms-control.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is a very popular exception when using a thread.Some operation are not thread safe (like accessing a control on a thread other than its own thread) so framework is preventing these kind of problems.
To solve it you can either use Control.Invoke method to call a delegate that is in the same thread the control or you can use a background worker.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) you can find a sample of first approach

and

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) you can find a sample of a background worker