# How to check if object is created in the main thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I encountered in question without an answer in WPF (C#), I would like some help.

I want to check if an object is created in the main(UI) thread, is there a way to do it?

(Object such as a list, collection, etc.)

## EDIT

I am trying to reduce the use of Dispatcher.Invoke (and Dispatcher.CheckAccsess), because it slows down the system.

I have an object that when it binding to the UI I need the Invoke, but many times it was created in a different thread and there is no need in Invoke and it can set from the current thread.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Can you tell a little more about what you are trying to resolve? Maybe there are other ways to fix whatever you are encountering.

Comment: First, define "main thread".

Comment: @DannyChen I assume he is referring to the UI thread...

Comment: Objects such as 'list, collection etc' don't have any thread affinity, so it's not really possible nor clear why you'd want to do this.

Comment: @PeterBons, I edit my question you invited to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the check in an Extension method:

```
public static void Invoke<T>(this T c, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    if (c.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()))
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)
    else
        action(c);
}
```

(based on [A better way to write extension method to invoke a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019896/a-better-way-to-write-extension-method-to-invoke-a-control))

Other then using extension methods to create better looking code there is no way to check what tread is used to create an object.

Are you using async/await? Because that might reduce the need to do this. Can you show some code where you are accessing the UI from another thread? Maybe you can reduce that situation.